# Unable to integrate SpringVault within my Web App

Tags: java, spring, hashicorp-vault, spring-vault

I am trying to integrate spring vault as an extra module in my web application. I have created a new service EncryptionService which makes a call to my Spring Vault ApiVaultClient as it is shown bellow :

My Vault configuration `VaultConfig.java` :

```
package com.myproject.encryption;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.vault.authentication.ClientAuthentication;
import org.springframework.vault.authentication.TokenAuthentication;
import org.springframework.vault.client.VaultEndpoint;
import org.springframework.vault.config.AbstractVaultConfiguration;
import org.springframework.vault.core.VaultTemplate;

@Configuration
public class VaultConfig extends AbstractVaultConfiguration {
    private Properties props;
    private String token;
    private String host;
    private int port;
    
    public VaultConfig() {
        this.props = new Properties();
        
        InputStream vaultConfig = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("vault-config.properties");

        if(vaultConfig!=null) {
            try {
                props.load(vaultConfig);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                //LOG.error(ex.getMessage());
            }
        } else {
            //LOG.error(new FileNotFoundException("property file vault-config.properties not found in the classpath"));
        }

        this.token = props.getProperty("vault.token");
        this.host = props.getProperty("vault.uri");
    }

    @Override
    public ClientAuthentication clientAuthentication() {
        return new TokenAuthentication(this.token);
    }

    @Override
    public VaultEndpoint vaultEndpoint() {
        VaultEndpoint endpoint = null;
        try {
            endpoint = VaultEndpoint.from(new URI(this.host));
        } catch (URISyntaxException ex) {
            //LOG.error(ex.getMessage());
        }
        return endpoint;
    }
    
    /*I added this method hoping that this might solve the bean creation problem of vaultOperations in ApiVaultClient but it didn't work out either*/
    @Bean
    public VaultTemplate getVaultTemplate() {
        VaultTemplate vaultTemplate = new VaultTemplate(vaultEndpoint(), clientAuthentication());
        return vaultTemplate;
    }

    /**
     * Setters & Getters
     */
    
    public Properties getProps() {
        return props;
    }
    
    public void setProps(Properties props) {
        this.props = props;
    }
    
    public String getToken() {
        return token;
    }
    
    public void setToken(String token) {
        this.token = token;
    }
    
    public String getHost() {
        return host;
    }
    
    public void setHost(String host) {
        this.host = host;
    }

    public int getPort() {
        return port;
    }

    public void setPort(int port) {
        this.port = port;
    }
}
```

My REST Client `ApiVaultClient.java` :

```
package com.myproject.encryption;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.vault.core.VaultOperations;
import org.springframework.vault.core.VaultTransitOperations;

@Component("apiVaultClient")
public class ApiVaultClient{
    @Autowired
    private VaultOperations vaultOperations;
    private VaultTransitOperations transitOperations;
    private String keyStore;
    private Properties props;
    
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        this.transitOperations = vaultOperations.opsForTransit();
        
        InputStream vaultConfig = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("vault-config.properties");
        this.props = new Properties();
        if(vaultConfig!=null) {
            try {
                props.load(vaultConfig);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                //LOG.error(ex.getMessage());
            }
        } else {
            //LOG.error(new FileNotFoundException("property file vault-config.properties not found in the classpath"));
        }

        this.keyStore = props.getProperty("vault.key.store");
    }
    
    public String encrypt(String clearText) {
        String cipherText = transitOperations.encrypt(this.keyStore, clearText);
        return cipherText;
    }
    
    public String decrypt(String cipherText) {
        String clearText = transitOperations.decrypt(this.keyStore, cipherText);
        return clearText;
    }

    public String getKeyStore() {
        return keyStore;
    }

    public void setKeyStore(String keyStore) {
        this.keyStore = keyStore;
    }

    public VaultOperations getVaultOperations() {
        return vaultOperations;
    }

    public void setVaultOperations(VaultOperations vaultOperations) {
        this.vaultOperations = vaultOperations;
    }

    public VaultTransitOperations getTransitOperations() {
        return transitOperations;
    }

    public void setTransitOperations(VaultTransitOperations transitOperations) {
        this.transitOperations = transitOperations;
    }

    public Properties getProps() {
        return props;
    }

    public void setProps(Properties props) {
        this.props = props;
    }
}
```

My `EncryptionService` implementation :

```
package com.myproject.business.service.impl;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import com.myproject.business.service.EncryptionService;
import com.myproject.encryption.ApiVaultClient;

public class EncryptionServiceImpl implements EncryptionService{

    @Autowired
    private ApiVaultClient apiVaultClient;
    
    @Override
    public String encrypt(String clearText) {
        return apiVaultClient.encrypt(clearText);
    }

    @Override
    public String decrypt(String cipherText) {
        return apiVaultClient.decrypt(cipherText);
    }

    public ApiVaultClient getApiVaultClient() {
        return apiVaultClient;
    }

    public void setApiVaultClient(ApiVaultClient apiVaultClient) {
        this.apiVaultClient = apiVaultClient;
    }

}
```

My `vault-config.properties` :

```
vault.uri=http://127.0.0.1:8200
vault.token=s.ty3r7is9tSlXfC4GFMHvwDa5
vault.key.store=transit/keys/store
```

My `serviceContext.xml` which lies in my business module :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd">
    
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.myproject.business.service.impl" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.myproject.encryption" />

    <!-- other services are skipped -->

    <bean id="encryptionService" parent="txnProxyTemplate">
        <property name="target">
            <bean class="com.myproject.business.service.impl.EncryptionServiceImpl">
                <property name="apiVaultClient" ref="apiVaultClient" />
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
    </beans>
```

When starting my application I get the following error :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'apiVaultClient': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.vault.core.VaultOperations com.myproject.encryption.ApiVaultClientImpl.vaultOperations; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'vaultTemplate' defined in class path resource [com/myproject/encryption/VaultConfig.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.vault.core.VaultTemplate org.springframework.vault.config.AbstractVaultConfiguration.vaultTemplate()] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientHttpRequestFactoryWrapper' defined in class path resource [com/myproject/encryption/VaultConfig.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.vault.config.AbstractVaultConfiguration$ClientFactoryWrapper org.springframework.vault.config.AbstractVaultConfiguration.clientHttpRequestFactoryWrapper()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.vault.support.SslConfiguration$KeyStoreConfiguration
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1148)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:636)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:934)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.vault.core.VaultOperations com.myproject.encryption.ApiVaultClientImpl.vaultOperations; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'vaultTemplate' defined in class path resource [com/myproject/encryption/VaultConfig.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.vault.core.VaultTemplate org.springframework.vault.config.AbstractVaultConfiguration.vaultTemplate()] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientHttpRequestFactoryWrapper' defined in class path resource [com/myproject/encryption/VaultConfig.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.vault.config.AbstractVaultConfiguration$ClientFactoryWrapper org.springframework.vault.config.AbstractVaultConfiguration.clientHttpRequestFactoryWrapper()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.vault.support.SslConfiguration$KeyStoreConfiguration
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:518)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'vaultTemplate' defined in class path resource [com/myproject/encryption/VaultConfig.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.vault.core.VaultTemplate org.springframework.vault.config.AbstractVaultConfiguration.vaultTemplate()] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientHttpRequestFactoryWrapper' defined in class path resource [com/myproject/encryption/VaultConfig.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.vault.config.AbstractVaultConfiguration$ClientFactoryWrapper org.springframework.vault.config.AbstractVaultConfiguration.clientHttpRequestFactoryWrapper()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.vault.support.SslConfiguration$KeyStoreConfiguration
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:603)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1057)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:953)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:921)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:864)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:779)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:490)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.vault.core.VaultTemplate org.springframework.vault.config.AbstractVaultConfiguration.vaultTemplate()] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientHttpRequestFactoryWrapper' defined in class path resource [com/myproject/encryption/VaultConfig.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.vault.config.AbstractVaultConfiguration$ClientFactoryWrapper org.springframework.vault.config.AbstractVaultConfiguration.clientHttpRequestFactoryWrapper()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.vault.support.SslConfiguration$KeyStoreConfiguration
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:592)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientHttpRequestFactoryWrapper' defined in class path resource [com/myproject/encryption/VaultConfig.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.vault.config.AbstractVaultConfiguration$ClientFactoryWrapper org.springframework.vault.config.AbstractVaultConfiguration.clientHttpRequestFactoryWrapper()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.vault.support.SslConfiguration$KeyStoreConfiguration
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:603)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1057)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:953)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:305)
    at com.myproject.encryption.VaultConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5cf9316c.clientHttpRequestFactoryWrapper(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.vault.config.AbstractVaultConfiguration.vaultTemplate(AbstractVaultConfiguration.java:108)
    at com.myproject.encryption.VaultConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5cf9316c.CGLIB$vaultTemplate$12(<generated>)
    at com.myproject.encryption.VaultConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5cf9316c$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$1da77a86.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:293)
    at com.myproject.encryption.VaultConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5cf9316c.vaultTemplate(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:160)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.vault.config.AbstractVaultConfiguration$ClientFactoryWrapper org.springframework.vault.config.AbstractVaultConfiguration.clientHttpRequestFactoryWrapper()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.vault.support.SslConfiguration$KeyStoreConfiguration
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:592)
    ... 58 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.vault.support.SslConfiguration$KeyStoreConfiguration
    at org.springframework.vault.support.SslConfiguration.unconfigured(SslConfiguration.java:323)
    at org.springframework.vault.config.AbstractVaultConfiguration.sslConfiguration(AbstractVaultConfiguration.java:225)
    at org.springframework.vault.config.AbstractVaultConfiguration.clientHttpRequestFactoryWrapper(AbstractVaultConfiguration.java:207)
    at com.myproject.encryption.VaultConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5cf9316c.CGLIB$clientHttpRequestFactoryWrapper$13(<generated>)
    at com.myproject.encryption.VaultConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5cf9316c$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$1da77a86.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:293)
    at com.myproject.encryption.VaultConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5cf9316c.clientHttpRequestFactoryWrapper(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:160)
```

I tried to follow what most tutorials propose by the book but in vain. Any help will be more than appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I have the same issue: `org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'clientHttpRequestFactoryWrapper' available`

It seems that this wrapper is not globally available, and at some point down the tree it is needed.